# Extract from DataRow or DataReader with one function

Tags: c#, .net, sql, datareader, datarow

I'm looking for a solution for how to be able to extract data from a database when using either a DataRow and a DataReader with only one function (or one base function).

My problem stems from the fact that sometimes I need a DataReader and sometimes I need a DataTable/DataRow but then in order to extract the data from those objects I need two seperate Data access methods because they do not share an interface.

Basically when my database structure changes, I don't want to have to go in and write the following data retrieval code in multiple functions:

```
someValue = dr["someValue"]
```

It's the same syntax and does the same thing so I want a function that shares that functionality regardless of whether I'm using a DataReader or DataTable/DataRow to extract the data from the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [CreateDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.createdatareader.aspx) method in DataTable class to access data through DbDataReader base class. Hence you can change the implementation but keep the mapping.

```
public List<MyType> GetMyTypeCollection(DbDataReader reader)
{
//mapping code here
}
```

It would be better if you can move to an ORM where you do not have to map manually.

Take a look at this micro ORM [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/)

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I needed! I had no idea that method existed.

Answer (score 2):

Use [this](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=143) article to convert the datareader to a datatable and then you can interface both as a datatable

So you would basically add this function that get's called from your dataLayer:

```
public DataTable ConvertDataReader(SqlDataReader dr)
{
  SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection); 
  DataTable dtSchema = dr.GetSchemaTable();
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();

  // You can also use an ArrayList instead of List<>
  List<DataColumn> listCols = new List<DataColumn>();            
  if(dtSchema != null) 
  {
     foreach (DataRow drow in dtSchema.Rows)
     {
        string columnName = System.Convert.ToString(drow["ColumnName"]); 
        DataColumn column = new DataColumn(columnName, 
                               (Type)(drow["DataType"]));
        column.Unique = (bool)drow["IsUnique"];
        column.AllowDBNull = (bool)drow["AllowDBNull"];
        column.AutoIncrement = (bool)drow["IsAutoIncrement"];
        listCols.Add(column);
        dt.Columns.Add(column);
     }
  }

  // Read rows from DataReader and populate the DataTable 
  while (dr.Read())
  {
    DataRow dataRow = dt.NewRow();
    for(int i = 0; i < listCols.Count; i++)
    {
      dataRow[((DataColumn)listCols[i])] = dr[i];
    }
    dt.Rows.Add(dataRow);
  }
}
```

And then in your function where you get the datatable, you would then do an if it's a dataReader, pass the reader to the function to return a datatable:

```
DataTable dtFromReader = ConvertDataReader(dr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean auto map sql query result's row to an entity? Like this?

```
public static List<T> ToList<T>(this IDataReader idr, int count) where T : new()
{
    if (idr == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("idr");

    if (idr.IsClosed)
        throw new ArgumentException("IDataReader is closed.");

    Type businessEntityType = typeof(T);
    List<T> entitys = new List<T>();
    Hashtable hashtable = new Hashtable();
    PropertyInfo[] properties = businessEntityType.GetProperties();

    int idx = 0;

    foreach (PropertyInfo info in properties)
    {
        hashtable[info.Name.ToUpper()] = info;
    }

    while (idr.Read())
    {
        if (count > 0)
            idx++;

        T newObject = new T();
        for (int index = 0; index < idr.FieldCount; index++)
        {
            PropertyInfo info = (PropertyInfo)hashtable[idr.GetName(index).ToUpper()];
            if (info != null && info.CanWrite)
            {
                try
                {
                    info.SetValue(newObject, idr.GetValue(index), null);
                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
        }

        entitys.Add(newObject);

        if (idx > count)
            break;
    }
    return entitys;
}
```

Comment: Db actions has a cost. Add reflection to it, it's going to be noticeably slower. You should rely on expression trees instead of reflection. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19845980/661933 for e.g. And make use of generics (use dictionary instead of hashtable)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternate solution I used a private function that took a dynamic argument.
Then added two public functions that took "DataRow" and "DataReader" arguments.
You can use this to limit the calls to known types or interfaces.

```
public MyResults DoStuff(DataRow dr)
{
    return ActualDoStuff(dr);
}

public MyResults DoStuff(DataReader dr) //IDataRecord is better if just reading
{
    return ActualDoStuff(dr);
}

private MyResults ActualDoStuff(dynamic dr)
{
    var rez = new MyResults();
    rez.someValue = dr["someValue"];
    return rez;
}
```

A word of warning though. You may need to re-write your load code slightly as the behavior of dr content accessed via string on a dynamic is slightly different. I.e.

```
if(dr["someValue"] == DBNull.Value)
```

might need to be changed to

```
if(dr["someValue"] is DBNull)
```

But this approach still avoids the duplicated load code issue.

Answer (score 0):

Create an adapter to hide implementation of `DataReader` to work with `DataTable/DataRow` codes